# Return results only if it doesn't contain a particular value?

Tags: mysql

I have 2 tables :-

Table `T`

```
 ID | val 
  1 | abcd 
  2 | 1234
  3 | asd 
  4 | lkj
```

And another table `M`

```
ID | T_ID | Type 
 1 | 1    |  I 
 2 | 1    |  S
 3 | 2    |  I
 4 | 2    |  I
 5 | 3    |  I
 6 | 4    |  S
```

I want to write a query that joins table `T` and `M` on `m.T_ID = T.ID` but it should not return `T.ID` if **any** `M` mapped to it has Type `S` i.e. the above set of data should return values `T.ID = 2,3` and not `1,4` because `M` mapped to it has Type `S`

One way to do it would be to write a inner query. Something like :-

```
SELECT T.id 
FROM   table1 T 
       JOIN table2 M 
         ON M.t_id = T.id 
WHERE  T.id NOT IN (SELECT m2.t_id 
                    FROM   table2 m2 
                    WHERE  m2.type = 'S')
```

But inner query can be very expensive as my table M has millions of rows. Is there a better way to do this ?

Comment: `where M.Type != 'S'` ?

Comment: what about improving your join condition such as `on M.T_ID = T.ID and Type = 's'` ?

Comment: If you already have a working query and want help to improve performace then show us the explain plan. Performance questions should include `EXPLAIN ANALYZE` and some information about table size, index, current time performance, desire time, etc. `Slow` is a relative term and we need a real value to compare.

[**MySQL**](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/15371/how-do-i-get-the-execution-plan-for-a-view)

Comment: The question is to exclude the row if any of them has a type='S' in the child table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a conditional `COUNT`

```
SELECT T.id 
FROM   table1 T 
JOIN   table2 M 
  ON   M.t_id = T.id 
GROUP BY T.id 
HAVING COUNT( CASE WHEN M.Type = 'S' THEN 1 END ) = 0
```

Mean you dont have `'S'` in that group.

Answer (score 1):

Not the prettiest but it seems to work

```
select T.ID 
from Table1 T 
left join Table2 M on M.T_ID = T.ID
group by T.Id
having sum(case when M.Type = 'S' then 1 else 0 end) = 0
```

You should check if it is actually less expensive in the execution plan.

Comment: Just personal preference because your `SUM` and my `COUNT` should produce same result. But is more obvious to future readers using `count`  because you are counting object. `SUM` is better on something like `SUM (Case when month = 'february'  THEN sales END)`

Answer (score -2):

You should look into LEFT JOIN as opposed to INNER JOIN.